# Residual current in electrolysis

Tags: electrolysis

On this site: https://water.lsbu.ac.uk/water/electrolysis.html there is a graph showing current-voltage characteristic for electrolysis of water:

[image: Current-voltage characteristic for electrolysis of water]

I am wondering, if I apply voltage lower than required to decompose water (lower than 1.23 V, like for example 0.8 V), will there still be residual current flow (called "background current" in the picture) and if yes, will the ions, that normally participate in chemical reactions at the electrodes, be charge carriers? Also, if there is current flow even with applied voltage below 1.23 V, how high is typical current (like in the range of μA or mA)?

Comment: According to the [footnote a](https://water.lsbu.ac.uk/water/electrolysis.html#a) in the page you provided, the [specific resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) of pure water, for example, is $\zeta = \rm 18\;M\Omega\cdot cm$.  The background current is therefore $I = U/R = UA/(\zeta \ell)$ with $A$ being the area of electrodes, $\ell$ distance between them, and $U$ applied voltage.

Comment: Also, as you can see in the picture, 1,23 is hardly enough - you need at least some 0.4-0.5 V of overpotential on top of that, to have significant reaction.